# Chainload Windows boot manager from another?

Tags: windows, bootmgr, boot-manager

Is it possible to use the Windows Boot Manager to chainload another Windows Boot Manager?

For example, (how) can I use a boot manager on `C:\bootmgr` that reads `C:\boot\BCD` to chainload another boot manager `D:\bootmgr` that uses `D:\boot\BCD`?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound: I have a UEFI and a legacy BIOS boot loader (installed on different disks -- one MBR, one GPT) and I want them to use the same Boot Configuration Database.

Comment: have you ruled out the possibility that your motherboard has the ability to boot to either one simply by changing the boot order?

Comment: @Ramhound: Huh? I'm trying to avoid having two BCD stores if possible -- I can already switch between OSes just fine.

Comment: Another use case would be to trick Windows into believing the system disk is another one, and allow it to be brought offline  (e.g. to pass it to a VM). If you use boot mannager from disk 1 to load windows from disk 2 you won't be able to bring offline either one

Answer (score 1):

BOOTMGR will look for the hive `\boot\bcd` on the partition it believes to be the active boot partition (usually the active partition on disk 0). On EFI machines, the EFI version of bootmgr will load `\boot\bcd` from the ESP (EFI System Partition) which is always FAT32 and usually around 100 MiB or so.

Your question is, however, very confusing. You state

> that reads **C:\boot\BCD** to chainload another boot manager D:\bootmgr that uses **D:\boot\BCD**

But then say

> Huh? I'm trying to avoid having two BCD stores if possible

In the example you give of what you're trying to achieve, aren't those two different BCD files on two different partitions?

So I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do. If you're trying to make the legacy BOOTMGR load the same BCD database that the EFI BOOTMGR uses, yes, that would be possible. You'll need to modify the emulation bootrecord on your disk (the fake MBR that's used to stop machines that don't understand GPT from reinitializing disks and losing data) to indicate the presence of at least two partitions, being the ESP and the Windows partition, with the ESP marked as active.

That way, if a BIOS in legacy mode (or a BIOS that doesn't support UEFI) attempts to start your machine from a GPT disk with your modified emulation MBR, it'll see the ESP partition as a "regular" boot partition and load from it (via its bootsector, which you would need to make sure was correctly written with a tool like `bootsect` or `bootrec`) BOOTMGR which, in turn, would read the `\boot\bcd` on the self-same partition.

Comment: Sorry, I realize my comment was confusing -- what I meant was that I don't want to have two BCD stores that have *duplicate* entries (which is what would be otherwise required if I can't do chainloading to load a different BCD store). It's fine to have two separate stores; they just shouldn't overlap. Instead, what I want is to have either boot loader be able to load the *other* boot loader's entries, so that I don't have to list an operating system twice (once in each). Is this possible?

Comment: @Mehrdad: this is a bewildering and contradictory specification. Each bootloader needs entries for each OS it boots and each chainloaded boot application (typically another bootloader). There will necessarily be N entries in each of N bootloaders if each can chainload the others.

Comment: @kreemoweet: what exactly is "contradictory" here? There is no fundamental reason why each boot loader would need a separate database. It may be that that is the current state of affairs, but there is nothing "contradictory" or "bewildering" about it. I can very well imagine an alternative system in which that wouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 1):

You want the first bootmgr to load a secondary bootmgr instead of loading one of the typical OS boot-loaders

"if it works" you should add the following entries to the first C:\boot\BCD

```
bcdedit /create /d "Chainloaded Bootmgr" /application BOOTSECTOR
bcdedit /set {ID} device partition=d:
bcdedit /set {ID}  path \bootmgr
bcdedit /displayorder {ID} /addlast
```

this should create the menu entry "Chainloaded Bootmgr"; when triggered it should load the second bootmgr from D:

Comment: The author already said he didn't want to use this solution.

Comment: @Ramhound where did he say that? these 2 stores do not overlap and that's "exactly" what the author wants.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, however you may try the tool `EasyBCD` [Download EasyBCD here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml)! & `VisualBCD` [Download VisualBCD here](http://www.boyans.net/)!

These tools help you to edit and modify the bootloaders.

Comment: What is not clear about the question exactly? And yes I know about EasyBCD and VisualBCD, those don't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

---

### You want:

Boot `C:`, starting `bootmgr` with specially configured BCD in `C:\Boot`.
One boot entry in this BCD should start another `bootmgr` on `D:\` which loads the BCD on `d:\Boot` with different boot entries.

Correct?

---

To do that:

Get an image of the boot sector of `D:\`

1. Start Linux, `dd if=/dev/sda2 of=bootsec_D.img bs=512 Count=1^`
2. `mount /dev/sda2 /media/sda2`
3. `cp bootsec_D.img /media/sda2`
4. `umount /dev/sda2`

This `bootsec_D.img` can then be chainloaded with `bootmgr` the usual way.
For example, with Visual_BCD adding a new bootsector loader. Configure Partition and path properly.

---

Hope that helped.

It worked on my Computer, hopefully at yours, too.

Comment: The author already said he didn't want to use a solution like this.

Answer (score 0):

The method specified by user Pat worked for me. Unfortunately, the downloaded bootmgr used an old configuration file (BCD).

However, I found that grub4dos can automatically find and load bootmgr along the chain. To do this, you do not even need to specify a partition on the disk.

You will need BOOTICE, "grldr" from the grub4dos image, as well as EasyBCD/bcdtool/Visual BCD, or you can use the command line (Pat user method).

1. Download grub4dos
2. Unpack "grldr" to the root of the partition with the original bootmr
3. Add the BCD application/bootsec entry via EasyBCD/bcdtool/Visual BCD/cmd, specify the boot partition and the path /grldr
4. Next to grldr, create a menu.lst file and specify the following:

- 

```
debug off
default 0 
timeout 30
graphicsmode -1 640:800

title find bootmgrD
find --set-root /bootmgrD
chainloader /bootmgrD
```

5. Copy the Boot, EFI folders and the bootmgr file to the desired partition and rename bootmgr to bootmgrD (or create a copy of this file with a new name).
6. For this partition in the BOOTICE, specify pbr "bootmgr" (although this may be optional)

You can use any name for bootmgr instead of bootmgrD. The name must be unique for each partiton